# Creating a Priority queue

Tags: c#, list, queue, hierarchy

I need to create a Priority Queue but Im a bit lost how to do it.
I have these 2 lists.

```
        //Medic List
        ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(01, "Antonio", 555444333, "antonio@gmail.com", "Dermatologista"));
        ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(02, "Lucas", 555444333, "lucas78@gmail.com", "Cardiologista"));
        ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(03, "Duarte", 555444333, "Duarte90@gmail.com", "Otorrino"));
        ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(04, "Marcos", 555444333, "marcos123@gmail.com", "Clinica Geral"));
        ListaMedico.Add(new Medico(05, "Pedro", 555444333, "Pedro12@gmail.com", "Pediatra"));
```

And

```
           //Sick People List
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100001, "Pedro", 914754123, "pedro@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100002, "Lucas", 974123214, "lucas91@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100003, "Rodrigo", 941201456, "rodrigo00@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100004, "Gaspar", 987453210, "gaspar@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100005, "Roberto", 974120219, "roberto@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100006, "Eduardo", 974120219, "edu@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100007, "Ismael", 974120219, "Isma@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100008, "Paulo", 974120219, "Paulo90@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
            ListaUtente.Add(new Utente(100009, "Ana", 974120219, "ana.90@gmail.com", GetRandomColor()));
```

Im using this code to assign random colors to my patients.

```
    static ConsoleColor[] colors = { ConsoleColor.Red, ConsoleColor.Green, ConsoleColor.Yellow, ConsoleColor.Magenta }; // Cores disponíveis para usar nas Senhas
    static ConsoleColor GetRandomColor()
    {

        return colors[random.Next(colors.Length)];
    }
```

I need a priority queue because the magenta ones are priority, then red, then yellow and finnaly green. How can I assign some patients to my doctors respecting this color hierarchy?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define the value of the enum item accordingly with your priority and retrieve the list items ordering by it.

```
public enum ConsoleColor { Magenta = 1, Red =2, Yellow = 3, Green = 4 }


ListaUtente.OrderBy(x => (int)x);
```

Comment: Thanks for your input. Gonna try this.

Comment: Its not working, any idea why? Do I place this inside my main() or do I need to create a new class.

Comment: @Dany4k You create an enum. He posted the code to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom order by to do that, but you must specify *how to order by priority*,

For example:

```
var orderedByPriority = ListaUtente.OrderBy(sick => 
    sick.Color == ConsoleColor.Magenta ? 1 :
    sick.Color == ConsoleColor.Red ? 2 :
    sick.Color == ConsoleColor.Yellow ? 3 : 4);
```

With this logic, you do not need to change your code.

Comment: I just did this and Im getting an error on Color. "Does not contain a definition for Color and no extension method Color.

Comment: @Dany4k Color is one example. You need to change `sick.Color` to `sick.TheNameOfThePropertyThatHoldsTheColorValueOnTheObjectUtente`

Comment: "sick" is one instance of the Utente Object. In your example, you do not provide the code for the Utente class definition, so "Color" in my example is just a placeholder property. You need to change it to the property that holds the color in the object "Utente".

Answer (score 0):

The main thing about a priority queue is that it should keep track of what's being added at various priorities and keep them in order. To do that you really need a correctly constructed data structure, or you're going to wind up dummying it up with calls to sort a built-in .NET structure over and over, which is bad syntactically and for performance.

There is an int-priority implementation of a priority queue that should work fine for your purposes here: [PriorityQueue source](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/e740e7c10f405a41cdedc9b778f30059d6d22936/SharpByte.Core/Collections/PriorityQueue.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

A concurrent version, if you need that feature, is here: 
[ConcurrentPriorityQueue source](https://bitbucket.org/jeff_varszegi/sharpbyte-net-public/src/e740e7c10f405a41cdedc9b778f30059d6d22936/SharpByte.Core/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentPriorityQueue.cs?at=master&fileviewer=file-view-default)

An int-ordered priority queue works fine with enumerations because enumerations are integer types with some syntactic sugar added. :) Hope this helps!